# Purpose of passing state to CancellationToken.Register() in C#

Tags: c#, cancellation-token

In C#, the `Register` method of the `CancellationToken` has several overloads. Two of them are:

```cs
public CancellationTokenRegistration Register(Action callback);
public CancellationTokenRegistration Register(Action<object?> callback, object? state);
```

The second overload can be used to pass some arbitrary state to the callback that is invoked on cancellation. However, I cannot understand its purpose. If you need to use some state in the callback, why dont you simply use the first overload and capture the state in the action?

```cs
CancellationToken ct = ...;
MyState state = ...;
ct.Register(() => SomeFunctionThatNeedsState(state));
```

Using the second overload seems to be unnecessary complicated:

```cs
CancellationToken ct = ...;
MyState state = ...;
ct.Register(innerState => SomeFunctionThatNeedsState((MyState)innerState), state);
```

I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) and the tutorial [register callbacks for cancellation requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-register-callbacks-for-cancellation-requests). I also found many other tutorials about cancellation in C# online. However, they rarely mention the second overload and if so, they only explain *how* you can pass the state but not *why* you would want to do so.

Comment: Why did you prefer to use an addtional delegate? The method can be called like this: `ct.Register(SomeFunctionThatNeedsState, state);`

Comment: @shingo No, the method cannot be called like this. The function takes a `MyState` argument, but the cancellation token passes the argument as `object?`.

Comment: Is it difficult to change the signature of the method to take an object argument?

Comment: @shingo The example is just for demonstration purposes. Thanks to the answer of the other question, I now understand that you may save an allocation by not creating a new delegate.